# 0xc0000225 Error on Windows Installation to GPT (UEFI)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, uefi

I am attempting to install Arch linux and dual boot it with windows. As I am running a modern UEFI system, I have put my SSD (see Specs below) in GPT format (losing my original windows installation in the process) where I plan on installing the UEFI boot loader, Windows, and Arch. At the moment I'm trying to reinstall Windows 7 (Professional x64), so I can do a UEFI boot. When I use Rufus to create a bootable GPT USB drive, I get the boot error 0xc0000225. When I try to do it manually with these (http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials...e-windows.html) instructions, my computer does not recognize my flash drive as bootable (it gives the insert proper boot media error). I am using this (http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59186.iso) for the ISO, I also have an old installation disc. Booting the ISO without modification in Legacy BIOS works just fine, but I have no way to install windows to a GPT drive while booting in Legacy BIOS (Windows states it cannot be installed to a GPT drive, probably because it detects the system is running legacy bios instead of UEFI). How can I install Windows 7 onto GPT?

Specifications:
CPU: i5-4670k
Motherboard: Z87x-D3H Gigabyte
SSD: OCZ Vertex 3 (Set in GPT mode)
HDD: Western Digital Caviar Blue
Flash Drive: 8GB JetFlash Transcend USB 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Rufus to MBR for UEFI with FAT32 file system to cause it to partition the flash drive as an MBR drive with a single FAT32 partition which contains the Windows UEFI boot files. Additionally you may want to disconnect all other drives. I was having an issue where my HDD which contained a copy of my old SSD installation partition was being recognized as a valid boot drive. This was causing the 0xc0000225 error (in addition to the flash drive being partitioned with the GUID partition table.

Answer (score 3):

From [Resolving the dreaded Windows 8 0xC0000225 error](http://www.maximumpc.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=242035&start=0&sid=40f651e91c64399ffa25322ac03db078) :

> I've had this happen to me twice, all of a sudden Windows 8 refuses to
>   boot and gives an error code of 0xC0000225 (or something) and anything
>   you do won't fix it. The problem is that since for whatever reason
>   Windows thinks there's no bootloader, it refuses to boot. Period. You
>   can't even go into the recovery environment, which is my biggest
>   complaint at Microsoft.
>
> In any case, there's one way I've found to resolve this. If you have
>   access to another computer, take out the affected computer's primary
>   drive and find a way to mount it in the system (internally,
>   externally, whatever). Then do the following:
>
> - Open command prompt as an administrator
> - Type in "diskpart"
> - Type in "list disk". Find out which disk the affected drive is.
> - Type in "select disk #", where # is the affected drive's number
> - Type in "list partition", find the partition number of the system partition (it's usually 100MB, 200MB, or 300MB), then type in "select
>     partition #", where # is the system partition's number.
> - Type in "assign letter=z", assuming you don't have a Z: drive.
> - Exit out of diskpart by pressing CTRL+C
> - Type in BCDBoot   `[Drive letter of affected drive's Windows partition]:\Windows /S Z: /F UEFI`   So if the affected drive's
>     Windows partition is say G:\, you would type in BCDBoot G:\Windows /S
>     Z: /F UEFI
>
> It should fix the bootloader. If you can get into a recovery
>   environment on the affected computer, then this should work as well.